# How can I convert a PFUser into a String?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How can I convert a PFUser value type to a String to display it on a label?

Something like this:

`username = PFUser.getCurrentUser()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PFUser.currentUser() returns a PFObject with many different properties. You need to get the data out of the object and then put that on a string.

For instance, if you wanted the current user's username..

```
let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
```

Answer (score 0):

A PFUser is a subclass of a PFObject and therefore, has many properties such as:

```
  username

  password

  email
```

See Parse's documentation here: [PFUser](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/enableAutomaticUser)

So essentially you'd need to do:

```
let username = PFUser.getCurrentUser()?.username
```